# Thread slipping out of tension discs, off spring, upper lever or bobbin thread slips out of tension

Tags: sewing-machine

While sewing along a nice straight line the thread bunches, I look at the thread path and it is out from between the tension disks or not on the spring or the bobbin thread is out from under the tension. I do not understand what "machine gremlin" is attacking me.

Comment: I finally had to take my machine to be serviced. I don't know what all they did, but it is fixed at the cost of $98.

Comment: I have the same thing happening to me. I checked my tensions and so on. I watched a video where the guy was saying to put the thread between disk 2 and 3. (I was putting it between disk 1 and 2 before) i was having mass loops on the bottom. I tried between 2 and 3 disk and did one seem with no problem then ran out of the thread i needed. But didn't have any loops. I want to also know why this happens

Answer (score 2):

That sounds frustrating! The easy things to do first are to be sure you are using good quality thread; rethread your machine, both top thread and bobbin thread; replace your needle with a new one and make sure it's inserted all the way and in the right direction (the flat side toward the back is how I insert mine); make sure you have the correct bobbin size, that the bobbin is inserted correctly, and that the bobbin thread was filled correctly (not loose or crooked).  From there, if these haven't solved your problem, you need to check your bobbin and thread tensions.  Most machines have a little screw on the bobbin case that you can loosen or tighten.  Adjusting the top thread tension is different on different machines, but I've used machines with those tension disks you mention and suggest you make sure you start out with the thread between the disks and not to the side. Then adjust the tension by tightening or loosening the disks, there is usually a thumb screw for that.  If you have the User's Guide for your machine, there should be a section about thread and bobbin tension, how to adjust them, and a table showing ranges of tensions for commonly used fabric types.  If you don't have that Guide, you may have to experiment.  You may also have to experiment every time you sew on different thickness and fabric types.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Abbie. I did all of the things you mentioned before posting my question. I guess I probably need to have my machine looked at by a tech. Unless maybe someone else has a different suggestion. It really perplexes my how it slips out of the disks.

Comment: So sorry.  Please let us know how you solve the issue!